# Semantics of the 'store-value' and 'use-value' restarts in the Common Lisp error handling system

Tags: exception, error-handling, lisp, common-lisp, condition-system

I've been reading the excellent book by Peter Seibel [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) in order to address some research I've been doing related with the Common Lisp error handling system.

Although I have read the explanation in the book and tried to dig some information in the net I have been not capable of understand the meaning and the usage of the `STORE-VALUE` and `USE-VALUE` restarts. Can someone explain what is the purpose of these functions?

```
;;; Example of the STORE-VALUE and USE-VALUE restarts

(defun careful-symbol-value (symbol)
   (check-type symbol symbol)
   (restart-case (if (boundp symbol)
                     (return-from careful-symbol-value 
                                 (symbol-value symbol))
                     (error 'unbound-variable
                            :name symbol))
     (use-value (value)
       :report "Specify a value to use this time."
     value)
     (store-value (value)
       :report "Specify a value to store and use in the future."
       (setf (symbol-value symbol) value))))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example in [Lispworks](http://www.lispworks.com/).

Let's define a class `foo` with a slot `bar`.

```
CL-USER 26 > (defclass foo () (bar))
#<STANDARD-CLASS FOO 4020001723>
```

We need an instance:

```
CL-USER 27 > (make-instance 'foo)
#<FOO 402000339B>
```

Now we try to access the unbound slot of that object. Note that `*` accesses the result of the previous evaluation.

```
CL-USER 28 > (slot-value * 'bar)
```

We are getting an error and a bunch of restarts:

```
Error: The slot BAR is unbound in the object #<FOO 402000339B>
    (an instance of class #<STANDARD-CLASS FOO 4020001723>).
  1 (continue) Try reading slot BAR again.
  2 Specify a value to use this time for slot BAR.
  3 Specify a value to set slot BAR to.
  4 (abort) Return to level 0.
  5 Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.
```

Number 2 is a [use-value](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/r_use_va.htm) restart and number 3 is a [store-value](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/r_store_.htm) restart.

Let's get the list of restarts:

```
CL-USER 29 : 1 > (compute-restarts)
(#<RESTART ABORT 4020009EB3>       #<RESTART ABORT 4020009F53>
 #<RESTART NIL 402000585B>         #<RESTART USE-VALUE 40200058DB>
 #<RESTART STORE-VALUE 402000595B> #<RESTART ABORT 40200059DB>
 #<RESTART ABORT 4020005A7B>       #<RESTART ABORT 41700D2503>)
```

In LispWorks we can get the current condition object with `:cc`.

```
CL-USER 30 : 1 > :cc
#<UNBOUND-SLOT 40200056F3>
```

Find the restart:

```
CL-USER 31 : 1 > (find-restart 'store-value *)
#<RESTART STORE-VALUE 402000595B>
```

Let's print it:

```
CL-USER 32 : 1 > (princ *)
Specify a value to set slot BAR to.
#<RESTART STORE-VALUE 402000595B>
```

Also for the `use-value` restart:

```
CL-USER 33 : 1 > :cc
#<UNBOUND-SLOT 402000B293>

CL-USER 34 : 1 > (find-restart 'use-value *)
#<RESTART USE-VALUE 402000B47B>

CL-USER 35 : 1 > (princ *)
Specify a value to use this time for slot BAR.
#<RESTART USE-VALUE 402000B47B>
```

Comment: @GoZoner, why is that? It's as good as "+1 for shamrock green".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a very simplistic explanation: `use-value` will use the value you give it only **once**, and the next time you hit the same place, it will error again. `store-value` will only ask you once for correction.

Imagine the situation: you are iterating over an array, and in some place you mistyped the index variable, say, `j` instead of `i`. If you choose to `use-value` once you hit the non-existing variable, it will keep asking you until the end of the loop. But if you choose to `store-value`, then it will try to use whatever you gave it and if it worked, will continue silently until the end of the loop.

Comment: Not a very good example, because `store-value` will assign `j`, but the iteration updates `i`. The errors will stop, but it will use the same value each time through the loop, rather than the loop index.